# Sup of product of sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets from $\mathbb{R}$

How to prove that

$$\sup(AB)=\max\{\sup(A)\sup(B),\sup(A)\inf(B), \sup(B)\inf(A),\inf(A)\inf(B)\} $$

where $AB=\{a\cdot b, a\in A, b\in B\}$ 
Edit1:

I prove this  by distinguishing 4 cases A positive or negative or B positive or negative

But what about if $A=[-1,4]$ and $ B= [-3,6]$ how to do ?

Comment: I think you should argue on the sign of sup(A), inf(A), sup(B), inf(B). Try to figure out some specific example, you will see how it works.

Comment: yes I edited my question @dynamic

Comment: We need to consider 9 cases (based on possible signs of sup and inf of A and B) for instance: Case 1: Sup(A)>0, inf(A)<0, sup(B)>0, inf(B)<0, then sup(AB) should be max{sup(A)sup(B), inf(A)inf(B)}. and similarly for other cases.

Comment: You might divide it into sub-cases, with $A_1 = [-1,0], A_2=[0,4]$ and similarly for $B$.